# No puedo actualizar un div al enviar un formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de actualizar un div al enviar un formulario, pero tengo un error 404

> jquery.min.js:2 POST Https://xxxx.com.ar/Home/@Url.Action(%22Pagination2%22,%22Home%22) 404 (Not Found)

Este es mi formulario:

```
 <form action="~/Home/PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2" method="post" id="ajax_submit_siguiente">
       <button class="siguiente-imagen @ViewData["btnSiguiente"]" id="btnSiguientePaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
             Siguiente
       </button>
 </form>
```

Mi Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#ajax_submit_siguiente").submit(function (e) {

        console.log("Llega a la funcion")
        // prevent regular form submit
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("prevent Default")

        var data = {
            'paginacion': 'siguiente',
            'entrega': $("#btnSiguientePaginacion").val()
        }
        console.log("Data cargada")

        console.log("Entra AJAX")
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2","Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("result: " + result);

                // refresh
                $(" #container-galeria-imagenes").load(window.location.href + " #container-galeria-imagenes ");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Y mi controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2(string paginacion, string entrega)
{
  List<PedidoViewModel> list;

  // WMás codigo....

  return Json(list);
}
```

Soy muy nuevo con Ajax.. Por lo que lei en la documentacion es así omo se hace para refrescar un div en vez de toda una pagina web...

Comment: Tu código js lo tienes dentro del archivo .cshtml de tu formulario o es un .js aparte?

Comment: está dentro de un archivo js aparte! Sé que está funcionando porque tengo otras funciones que éstan funcionando correctamente, pero que no chocan con ésta parte del codigo

Comment: El problema es que estás usando syntax de Razor (@Url.Action) en un archivo aparte, allí no te va a funcionar. Tienes que incluirlo en el .cshtml o envíalo como parámetro de la función esa url

Comment: Ahi cambie la url por `url: 'PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2'` y ahora tengo un 405... nose si es un problema de CORS o qué...

Comment: Deberías de enviar /Home/PaginacionGaleriaImagenes2

Comment: Es raro... me tira error `GET [my pagina] 405 (Method Not Allowed)` pero mi metodo es POST...

Comment: el dominio es el mismo, por lo que no deberia tener problemas de CORS